# Excel VBA code that copys tab and duplicates it 4 times and then renames the tabs issue between builds

Tags: excel, vba, version, rename

I am trying to run the below excel vba code to copy the current worksheet 4 times and then rename the newly created tabs. This code works fine on my home version of excel build 2312 however at work using excel build 2302 this code duplicates the original tab 4 times but fails to rename the tabs, it does not give any compiling error.

Any idea why this would work in one instance and not the other:

```
Sub CopyAndRenameWorksheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim originalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Set reference to the current worksheet named "RCA Dashboard"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set originalSheet = Sheets("RCA Dashboard")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if the sheet exists
    If originalSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet 'RCA Dashboard' not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy the current worksheet to 4 new tabs
    For i = 1 To 4
        originalSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ' Set reference to the newly created sheet
        Set newSheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ' Rename the new sheet
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                newSheet.Name = "RCA Dash"
            Case 2
                newSheet.Name = "LC Needed"
            Case 3
                newSheet.Name = "Escalation 1"
            Case 4
                newSheet.Name = "Escalation 2"
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a hidden worksheet at the end? Then `newSheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)` will always refer to the hidden one.

Comment: `Set newSheet = ActiveSheet` instead of `Set newSheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)` should fix it

Comment: Your code also works for me using Excel version 2312.